# pyspark, get rows where first column value equals id and second column value is between two values, do this for each row in a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

So I have one pyspark dataframe like so, let's call it dataframe a:

```
    +-------------------+---------------+----------------+
    |                reg|           val1|           val2 |
    +-------------------+---------------+----------------+
    |             N110WA|     1590030660|   1590038340000|
    |             N876LF|     1590037200|   1590038880000|
    |             N135MH|     1590039060|   1590040080000|
```

And another like this, let's call it dataframe b:

```
    +-----+-------------+-----+-----+---------+----------+---+----+
    |  reg|      postime|  alt| galt|      lat|      long|spd| vsi|
    +-----+-------------+-----+-----+---------+----------+---+----+
    |XY679|1590070078549|   50|  130|18.567169|-69.986343|132|1152|
    |HI949|1590070091707|  375|  455|  18.5594|-69.987804|148|1344|
    |JX784|1590070110666|  825|  905|18.544968|-69.990414|170|1216|
```

Is there some way to create a numpy array or pyspark dataframe, where for each row in dataframe a, all the rows in dataframe b with the same reg and postime between val 1 and val 2, are included?

Comment: Can you please check and let me know if you are looking for something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below solution -- and let us know if works or anything else is expected ?

I have modified the imputes a little in order to showcase the working solution--

**Input here**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([('N110WA',1590030660,1590038340000), ('N110WA',1590070078549,1590070078559)],[ "reg","val1","val2"])
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([('N110WA',1590070078549)],[ "reg","postime"])
df_a.show()
```

**df_a**

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
|   reg|         val1|         val2|
+------+-------------+-------------+
|N110WA|   1590030660|1590038340000|
|N110WA|1590070078549|1590070078559|
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

**df_b**

```
+------+-------------+
|   reg|      postime|
+------+-------------+
|N110WA|1590070078549|
+------+-------------+
```

**Solution here**

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
#df_a = df_a.join(df_b,'reg','left')
df_a = df_a.withColumn('condition_col', F.when(((F.col('postime') >= F.col('val1')) & (F.col('postime') <= F.col('val2'))),'1').otherwise('0'))
df_a = df_a.filter(F.col('condition_col') == 1).drop('condition_col')
df_a.show()
```

**Final Output**

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   reg|         val1|         val2|      postime|
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|N110WA|1590070078549|1590070078559|1590070078549|
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming `df_a` and `df_b` are both pyspark dataframes, you can use an inner join in pyspark:

```
delta = val
df = df_a.join(df_b, [
    df_a.res == df_b.res,
    df_a.posttime <= df_b.val1 + delta,
    df_a.posttime >= df_b.val2 - delta
], "inner")
```

Will filter out the results to only include the ones specified

Comment: What is the significance of delta?